# Send notifications on database php laravel mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a button that sends a notification. This is the request button. Only what I write to the toArray method is sent to the database in the data field. Now this is my 'message'. How can I change the data field outside the Notify.php file? That is, when the request button is pressed, a form should be opened, into which data is entered, which are then sent to the database instead of 'message'.First, tell me at least how I can fill in the data field, and I'll figure it out with the form myself. I am new to php laravel. I hope you can help me.
web.php:

```
<?php
use App\User;
use App\Notifications\Notify;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
Route::name('user.')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/private',function (){

        return view('private');
    });

    Route::view('/private','private')->middleware('auth')->name('private');
    Route::get('/login',function(){
        if(Auth::check()){return redirect(route('user.private'));}
//        Проверка на авторизацию пользователя. Если уже авторизован, то редирект на страницу профиля
        return view('login');
    })->name('login');
    Route::post('/login',[\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class,'login']);
    Route::get('/logout',function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');
    Route::get('/registration', function () {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return view('registration');
    })->name('registration');
    Route::post('/registration',[\App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController::class,'save']);
    Route::get('/private/request',function (){

        $users = User::all();
        Notification::send($users,new App\Notifications\Notify);
       return redirect(route('user.private'));
    });
    Route::get('/private/markAsRead',function (){

        auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
        return redirect()->back();
    });
});
```

private.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Профиль
@endsection
@section('content')
    <p>Только для аутентифицированых пользователей</p>
    <a href="/logout"><button onlick="return false;">LogOut</button></a> <p>
    <?php $id = Auth::id();
        $user = DB::table('users')->find($id);
    ?>
        {{$user->surname}}
       {{$user->name}}
       {{$user->fathers_name}}
       {{$user->number}}
       {{$user->studies}}

    <p>   <a href="/private/request"><button onlick="return false;">Request</button></a> <p>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <li class ='dropdown'>

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
            <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count()}}</span>
        </a>
    <li ><a href="/private/markAsRead" style="color: green">Mark all as Read</a></li>
        <ul >
        @foreach(auth()->user()->readNotifications as $notification)
            <li><a href="#"> {{$notification->data['data']}}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
            @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                <li style="background-color: lightgray"><a href="#"> {{$notification->data['data']}}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>

    </li>


@endsection
```

Notifications/Notify.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class Notify extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {

        return [
            'data' => 'message'
        ];
    }

}
```

This is screen from my database:
Here, instead of message, there should be my data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxJLZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use attributes in notifiable object not just typing the attributes (message) like this:

```
$notifiable->message
```